# Masterpage blocking search bar

Tags: asp.net, winforms, master-pages

I have a page with a gridview that displays results from a query and has paging and a search bar.  It works fine when I load it by itself with not master page however when I add the master page to it all the controls disappear.  below is the code with the master page and without

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" 
Runat="Server">
<%@ Import Namespace="GridView" %>


<div>
     <div align="center" class="padded" >
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
Font-Size="Large" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Refresh_Click">
</asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:Button ID="Refresh" runat="server" OnClick="Refresh_Click" 
Text="Search" Visible="False" />
</div>
<div>
    <cc1:HTMLGridView ID="HTMLGridView1" runat="server" 
OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound2"/>
   </div>
```

Here is the code that works with no master page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register assembly="GridView" namespace="GridView" tagprefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
     <div align="center" class="padded" >
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
Font-Size="Large" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Refresh_Click">
</asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:Button ID="Refresh" runat="server" OnClick="Refresh_Click" 
Text="Search" Visible="False" />
</div>

    <cc1:HTMLGridView ID="HTMLGridView1" runat="server" 
OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound2" allowDeleting="False" allowEditing="False" 
allowView="False"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I also added the reference to the web.config file but I have had no luck

```
<add tagPrefix="cc1" namespace="GridView" assembly="GridView" />
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: show your `Master Page` , How the code looks in it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<%@ Import Namespace="GridView" %>
```

before

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" 
Runat="Server">
```

Comment: Still no luck. It isn't showing the search bar or paging.